# In Arrow, why was Starling City renamed Star City?

Tags: arrowverse, arrow

In *Arrow*, they changed "Starling City" to be "Star City", why is that?

Comment: Are you asking why the city was renamed within the story later in the show or are you asking why they changed Star City from the comics into Starling City for the TV-show to begin with? Please try to add a little more context to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [Wikia](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Star_City) explains

> Initially, the city was named Starling City. However, following his takeover of Queen Consolidated, Ray Palmer wished to have the city rebranded as "Star City" in an **attempt to rejuvenate its populace** after the events of the Glades Earthquake and the subsequent invasion of Slade Wilson's army.
>
> After Ray Palmer's apparent death following a further terrorist attack by Ra's al Ghul, **the city was rechristened as Star City in his honor.**